# Select events matching a key using Reactor

Tags: java, spring, reactor

Using reactor(https://github.com/reactor/reactor) i notify a few events like

```
 commandReactor.notify("CREATE_CUSTOMER", Event.wrap(customer));
 commandReactor.notify("CREATE_ORDER", Event.wrap(order));
```

How do i implement a selector which selects all events starting with "CREATE"? Something like

```
@Selector(value = "CREATE*", reactor = "@commandReactor")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `RegexSelector` [1] to do that:

```
    commandReactor.notify("CREATE_(.+)", Event.wrap(obj));
```

or, using the annotations:

```
    @Selector(value = "CREATE_(.+)", type = SelectorType.REGEX)
```

Then in your handler, you can inspect the capture group by looking at the header for `group1` to `groupN`:

```
new Consumer<Event<Object>>>() {
  public void accept(Event<?> ev) {
    String type = ev.getHeaders().get("group1");
    if("CUSTOMER".equals(type)) {
      // handle customers
    } else if("ORDER".equals(type)) {
      // handle orders
    }
}
```

[1] - http://reactor.github.io/docs/api/reactor/event/selector/RegexSelector.html